# ОПП. Как передать свойства внутрь класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Есть класс родитель. Который используется повсеместно в коде. Я пытаюсь воспользоваться одним из его потомков и передать значение переменной, чтобы внутри метода родителя воспользоваться этой переменной. Но почему то не выходит.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
<?
    class class1{
        public $value;
        
        public function setFlag($flag)
        {
            $this->value = $flag;
        }

        public function getFlag(){
            return $this->value;
        }
            
        function registerVar(){
            $this->value; // почему ту является null
        }
    }
    class class2 extends class1{
        function fu2(){
            $this->registerVar();
        }
    }
    class class3 extends class2{
        function fu3(){
            $this->fu2();
        }
    }
    
    class class4{
    //  точка входа
    //  Этот метод, дергается ajax
        public function indexAction(){ 
            $module = new class3();
            $module->setFlag(true);  // что я передаю и надеюсь увидеть
            $module->fu3();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: И конструктором я не могу воспользоваться. (

Comment: не ясно... там где ты пишешь `почему ту является null`... ..пиши полный код...... как ты получаешь значение

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/_mKslBgukaecnxSwVTD_rg в методе все отлично, переменная имеет то значение которое задано. Если надо ее отуда вернуть, то везде (во всей цепочке вызовов) должны быть операторы `return`, в противном случае не ясно, где вы имеете null

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот ты создал объект класса 4: `$obj = new class4();`

Вызвал метод: `$obj->indexAction();`

Внутри метода indexAction() у тебя и будет объект $module. Ты либо там же с ним продолжай что-то делать, например дополни: `var_dump($module->value);` тебе это `$obj->indexAction();` выдаст bool(true);

Либо создавай public $module поле внутри class4 и внутри indexAction() уже пиши:

```
$this->module = new class3();
$this->module->setFlag(true);
```

А потом уже через объект обращайся, например: `var_dump($obj->module->value);` тебе так же выдаст bool(true)

```
class class1
{
    public $value;
    public $asd;

    public function setFlag($flag)
    {
        $this->value = $flag;
    }

    public function getFlag()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    function registerVar($name)
    {
        $this->$name = $this->value;
    }
}

class class2 extends class1
{

}

class class3 extends class2
{

}

class class4
{
    public $module;
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->module = new class3();
        $this->module->setFlag(true);
    }
}

$zxcv = new class4();
$zxcv->indexAction();
$zxcv->module->registerVar('asd');
var_dump($zxcv->module->asd);
```

Если ты внутри метода создашь просто так объект, то только внутри метода он и будет доступен, метод выполнится и все, больше ты этот объект не увидишь, и значение которое там присвоил исчезнет.

Comment: лучше бы дождались ответа автора, как он именно и при каких условиях получает то, что получает, чем додумывать тут сценарий использования

Comment: Простите, я наверно вел в заблуждение, уважаемое общество.
К сожалению, я не могу вывести весь код, ибо его много. 
Точка входа. Метод indexAction() его запускают через ajax. А дальше через наследование последовательно запускаются методы, пока не доходят до метода registerVar(), где я пытаюсь получить переменную, но не выходит. (я попытаюсь более читабельный код, написать ниже.)

Comment: @ДраконДраконовичь а что ты дальше делаешь с this->value? Куда присваиваешь или что, после module->fu3()? Что происходит внутри registerVar? Я проверял код тоже, если вывести module->value, то там true, в значит и в методе registerVar тоже this->value true, не понимаю что у тебя не так ))